# facebook - if user liked page without user permission

Tags: facebook

Ok, a want to find out if guest liked my facebook fan page without logging in with facebook and getting permission.

All i have to do is:

1) getting user id of guest (how to do it without logging in?)
2) use fbl - SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid = UID and page_id = PAGEID

which will tell me if guest is user

3) send access token of administrator of page with fbl (how to get acces token of specific user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without authentification you will not be able to get the user id. Search for "facebook fan gate" or "facebook signed_request" and come back again if you like.

Comment: but there is cookie with facebook user id in www.facebook.com cookie folder, can this help to get user id?

Comment: No, you cannot access that cookie. No chance, accept you are on the domain facebook.com, but you are not.

Comment: How then there are such things without application? I was on site which have like locker, i know how to make like locker with facebook event.subscribe, but on that site if a liked page and come over i would get full content, so they somehow have abbility to see if i liked page...

Comment: Ok , i get it now, they are using tottaly different approach with adding #xxxxx in link, and that is not i am looking for. Just to not open new question, i will ask here - is it possible when user log in with facebook in your page to set him autimatic to like my fanpage offcourse if ge give permission for that ( if such permission exists)

Comment: Fortunately such permission does not exist. By the way, you should not ask another unrelated question in a comment. You probably will not get any usefull answer. stackoverflow is not a forum, it is a Q&A site. Please read the FAQ.